# Discrete Symmetries in the Dirac Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, dirac-equation

I am self studying Quantum Field Theory and am using the book *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by Peskin and Schroeder. I am currently working on problem 3.8 (Bound States) and was able to do part a's charge conjugation part. However, I am slightly stuck on the parity part. I defined the positron + electron state to be

$$|\text{Positronium} \rangle = \sum_{i}A(k)a^{s,\dagger}(k)b^{s,\dagger}(-k)|0\rangle.$$

Applying the parity operator gets me:

$$\begin{align}P|\text{Positronium}\rangle &= \sum_{i}A(-k)a^{s,\dagger}(-k)b^{s,\dagger}(k)|0\rangle\\
&= (-1)^L\sum_{i} \eta_a \eta_b A(k)a^{s,\dagger}(k)b^{s,\dagger}(k)|0\rangle \\&= (-1)^{L+1}\sum_{i}A(k)a^{s,\dagger}(k)b^{s,\dagger}(k)|0\rangle.\end{align}$$

Technically, this does not equal $(-1)^{L+1}|\text{Positronium}\rangle$. I looked at the solutions provided by Zhong-Zhi Xianyu, but still saw the above problem. Why did the author of the solutions manual say that the last expression I had above equaled $(-1)^{L+1}|\text{Positronium}\rangle$?

Comment: You seem tobbe handling $a$ and $b$ differently. That seems strange to me.

Comment: @Oбжорoв Do you mean that the second equality should read $(-1)^L\sum_{i} \eta_a \eta_b A(k)a^{s,\dagger}(k)b^{s,\dagger}(-k)|0\rangle $ instead of $(-1)^L\sum_{i} \eta_a \eta_b A(k)a^{s,\dagger}(k)b^{s,\dagger}(k)|0\rangle $?

Comment: I haven't worked this out, I just find it strange you treat them differently. Why is that?

Comment: @Oбжорoв Where do I treat them differently? What do you exactly mean?

Comment: you are switching the sign of $A$ and $a$ in the second line, but not of $b$. Why?

Comment: @Oбжорoв I see; that makes sense. Thanks!